# Annoying error message when updating m2e project

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, plugins, m2e

We are using the m2e maven eclipse plugin (version 1.5.0.20140310-0533) for handling several projects/a multi-module project in Eclipse (version Kepler Service Release 2), respectivly. When changing the pom.xml of the projects, the projects mostly indicate an error, stating that "the project configuration is not up-to-date with pom.xml."

However, when we update the project configuration by right-clicking on the project in the package explorer, an error window is shown: "Could not update project  configuration Path must include project and resource name: /[Project name]". However, the project seems to be updated after performing this steps because the error disappears from the problems list of the project.

How can one get rid of this annoying error message ("Could not update project  configuration Path must include project and resource name: /[Project name]")?

Answer (score 0):

Try to import again the maven project into Eclipse...

Did you check out the project from SVN?